# max-key and min-key with several equal keys

Tags: clojure

Never thought would say that, but coming from c++, I miss sometimes something like the c++-standard in Clojure. Let's take for example `max-key` (or `min-key` for that matter):

```
(doc max-key)
;=clojure.core/max-key
;=([k x] [k x y] [k x y & more])
;=Returns the x for which (k x), a number, is greatest.
```

Hm, what if there are several items with the same key? [Clojuredocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max-key) hasn't more information on that. But experiments show:

```
(max-key count [1] [2])
;=[2]
(max-key count [1] [2] [3])
;=[3]
```

It seems, as if always the last element with the maximal key-value is returned.

But is it true? How can I be certain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is not specified, there is no guarantee. You should not depend on this behavior.

Certainly you could find out what will happen with the current implementation simply by reading it:

```
(defn max-key
  "Returns the x for which (k x), a number, is greatest."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([k x] x)
  ([k x y] (if (> (k x) (k y)) x y))
  ([k x y & more]
   (reduce1 #(max-key k %1 %2) (max-key k x y) more)))
```

It is clearly right-biased, so as implemented now you will get the rightmost element among all those that qualify. But again, because there is no guarantee, and any future version of Clojure may change this behavior.

Comment: So it is intentional, that there is not more information in docs, so the behavior can be changed one day if necessary?

Comment: I won't take any kind of stance on "why" it was done, whether it was intentional or not. All I can say for sure is that it is unspecified, and therefore could change without breaking any contract.

Comment: To perhaps clarify a bit: the closest thing we have to the C++ standard is function docstrings. It's not nearly as good, but it does mean I can easily tell you: it's not in the docstring, therefore it's not guaranteed one way or the other. What I can't say is why it's not in the docstring, or whether it will ever change.

Comment: It would be better to be explicit about what is *not* determined, as well as what is: a tradition that goes back to IBM's *Principles of Operations* for the 360 series.

Answer (score 1):

ClojureDocs has [a link to the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4915) (top right corner) so you can see the details and predict what will happen in any specific case. However, when more than one answer is available it is generally unspecified which item will be returned. Also, it can change with future versions of Clojure (which has happened before).

So, if you need a specific outcome (first, last, or something else) you may need to write a wrapper function to enforce the desired behavior in the event of ambiguous inputs.